# How to automatically enable addons in a startup script?

Tags: add-on, startup-file

My team want to share some addons and enforce the installation / enabling of some of theses.
We have a shared script directory that peoples have to add in the `File Paths`

I wrote a script that will read a list of required plugins and automatically enable them

The addons beeing in the `shared/scripts/addons` folder and this script beein in the `shared/scripts/startup` folder

```
import json
import addon_utils
import os

def enable_addons():

    current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    fp = os.path.join(current_directory, 'addons-manifest.json')

    manifest_file = open(fp)
    manifest_data = json.load(manifest_file)
    manifest_file.close()

    for addonName in manifest_data['addons']['default']:
        loaded_default, loaded_state = addon_utils.check(addonName)
        if loaded_state == False:
            print('Enabling ' + addonName + ' by default')
            addon_utils.enable(addonName, default_set=True, persistent=True)
        else:
            print(addonName + ' is already enabled')

def register():
    pass

def unregister():
    pass

enable_addons()
```

My script is working fine when ran from the Blender scripting tab, but when I open Blender I have this message:

```
Enabling '<MyAddon>' by default
Add-on not loaded: '<MyAddon>' cause: No module named '<MyAddon>'
```

I'm not familiar with Blender scripting, but I suppose that because when my script is ran, the addons aren't loaded yet?
Is there an event to register to wait for Blender to be ready?